@microsoft fetchEventSource not streaming the response
I want to fetch multi translations. when a translation is finished in the backend I want to return it back immediately to the frontend. I tested the backend using postman and everything seems fine.
I am using fetchEventSource as I wanted to send post request before streaming the response.
This is the useMultiTranslate hook:
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

import { useStore } from "@/store";
import { fetchEventSource } from '@microsoft/fetch-event-source';

export const useMultiTranslate = () => {
  const abortController = useRef(null);
  const src_lang = useStore((state) => state.srcLanguage);
  const clientIp = useStore((state) => state.clientIp);
  const [requestData, setRequestData] = useState(null);
  const [translations, setTranslations] = useStore((state) => [state.translations, state.setTranslations]);

  const url = 'api/v2/infere/multi';
  let headers = {};
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("token")) {
      headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!requestData)
        return;
    
    const { request, signal } = requestData;

    const streamTranslations = async () => {
      try {
        await fetchEventSource(url, {
          method: "POST",
          body: request,
          headers: headers,
          signal: signal,
          onmessage(ev) {
            console.log(`Received event: ${ev.data}`);
            setTranslations((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...JSON.parse(ev.data) }));
          },
          onerror(err) {
            console.error("Streaming error: ", err);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to stream response:', error);
      }
    };
    streamTranslations();
  }, [requestData?.signal]);

  const SubmitHandler = (input, sId) => {
    abortController.current = new AbortController();
    
    const request = new FormData();
    
    request.append("src_lang", src_lang);
    request.append("mt_dest_lang", "multi");

    const signal = abortController.current.signal;
    setRequestData({ request, signal });
  };

  return SubmitHandler;
};

I am triggering it using the returned submitHandler in TextboxToolbar.js
here is the TextboxToolbar.js:
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

import { Box, Stack, Button } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";
import { useReactMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder-2";
import useSWRMutation from "swr/mutation";

import { asrFetcher } from "@/models/NetworkManger";
import { useStore } from "@/store";
import { isFirefox, isStreaming, getStreamDebounce } from "@/config";
import AudioOutput from "../../AudioOutput";
import CopyAction from "../../CopyAction";
import FileInput from "../../FileInput";
import MicInput from "../../MicInput";
import MinimalAudioPlayer from "@/utils/MinimalAudioPlayer";
import ReverseTranslationAction from "../../ReverseTranslationAction";
import MultiLangTranslationAction from "../../MultiLangTranslationAction";
import ExpandAction from "../../ExpandAction";
import TranslateIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Translate";
import { useMultiTranslate } from "@/hooks/useMultiTranslate";

const fileFetcher = async (_key, { arg }) => {
  const { url } = arg;
  const file = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "blob" });
  return new File([file.data], `file.${isFirefox ? "ogg" : "webm"}`, {
    type: isFirefox ? "audio/ogg" : "audio/webm",
  });
};

const TextboxToolbar = ({
  showASR,
  showMic,
  showFileUpload,
  showTts,
  ttsMale,
  ttsFemale,
  playbackSpeed,
  textValue,
  disabled,
  showExpand,
  isExpanded,
  toggleExpand,
  showReverse,
  showReverseBtn,
  showMultiLang,
  showMultiLangBtn,
  setInputText,
  srcLanguage,
}) => {
  const { trigger: fileTrigger } = useSWRMutation("file", fileFetcher);
  const clientIp = useStore((state) => state.clientIp);
  const setSequenceID = useStore((state) => state.setSequenceID);
  const setIsAsrLoading = useStore((state) => state.setIsAsrLoading);
  const isReverseOpen = useStore((state) => state.isReverseOpen);

  // Add a new state variable to hold the MediaRecorder instance
  const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState(null);
  const sId = useStore((state) => state.sequenceID);
  const inputText = useStore((state) => state.inputText);

  // Add a new state variable to hold the audio data
  const audioData = useRef([]);
  const [playbackBlobUrl, setPlaybackBlobUrl] = useState(null);
  
  const SubmitHandler = useMultiTranslate();
  const isMultiLangOpen = useStore((state) => state.isMultiLangOpen);
  const currentUrl = useStore((state) => state.currentUrl); 
  const abortControllersRef = useRef([]);

  const multiTranslate = async () => {
    if (inputText.length)
      await SubmitHandler(inputText, sId);
  };

  return (
    <Stack
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        flexDirection: "row",
        minHeight: "50px",
      }}
    >
      <Box>
        {showASR && showMic && (
          <MicInput onRecord={onRecord} micStatus={status} />
        )}
        {showASR && showMic && playbackBlobUrl && (
          <MinimalAudioPlayer file={playbackBlobUrl} />
        )}
        {showASR && showFileUpload && <FileInput onFileUpload={fetchASR} />}
        {showTts && (
          <AudioOutput
            ttsMale={ttsMale}
            ttsFemale={ttsFemale}
            playbackSpeed={playbackSpeed}
          />
        )}
        {textValue && <CopyAction textValue={textValue} />}
        {showExpand && (
          <ExpandAction
            isExpanded={isExpanded}
            toggleExpand={toggleExpand}
          />
        )}
      </Box>

      <Box sx={{display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        {showReverseBtn && showReverse && <ReverseTranslationAction />}
        {!isReverseOpen && showMultiLangBtn && showMultiLang &&
          <>
            {disabled === false && <Button variant="outlined" onClick={multiTranslate}>
              <TranslateIcon />
              &nbsp;&nbsp;Translate
            </Button>}
            <MultiLangTranslationAction />
          </>
        }
      </Box>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default TextboxToolbar;

I removed some unimportant useEffects in the code which are irrelavent to my problem.
the problem is the reponse is returned when all translations are finished
What do I do wrong and thanks in advance.
I am expecting a solution to the unstreaming response returned to my frontend
